# org.bukkit.scoreboard.Team is null after initial Call

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I am making a skyblock plugin, but when I am creating the scoreboard, the team object which I use to change the balance in the scoreboard becomes null after initial call.
This is the exception:

```
[21:18:40 WARN]: [CustomSkyblock] Task #2 for CustomSkyblock v1 generated an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.scoreboard.Team.setSuffix(String)" because "balance" is null
        at io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.Main.lambda$onEnable$1(Main.java:102) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71) ~[Server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-741a1bd]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:350) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-741a1bd]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:723) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-741a1bd]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-741a1bd]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [Server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-741a1bd]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:
```

Here is the main class:

```
package io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock;

import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.commands.Eco;
import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.commands.ExampleCommand;
import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.economy.Economy;
import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.init.BalanceInit;
import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.listeners.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    public static final String SERVER_NAME = "§b9636's Test Server";

    private static String name, version;
    public static boolean requiresSave;
    public static final List<Player> playerScoreboardNeedsUpdate = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        super.onEnable();

        name = getDescription().getName();
        version = getDescription().getVersion();
        requiresSave = false;

        PluginManager pluginManager = Bukkit.getPluginManager();
        FileConfiguration config = getConfig();

        config.options().copyDefaults(true);

        if (!new File(config.getCurrentPath()).exists()) saveDefaultConfig();

        //Inits
        BalanceInit.init(config, 2500);

        //Commands
        Eco ecoCommand = new Eco(this);

        //Scoreboard
        ScoreboardManager scoreboardManager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
        Scoreboard scoreboard = scoreboardManager.getMainScoreboard();
        Objective title;
        Team balance,islandLevel,rank;
        if (scoreboard.getObjective("scoreboardTitle") != null) {
            balance = scoreboard.getTeam("§b§a§l§r");
        }
        else {
            title = scoreboard.registerNewObjective("scoreboardTitle","dummy");
            title.setDisplayName(SERVER_NAME.replaceFirst("§b","§7"));
            title.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);

            title.getScore("").setScore(7);
            title.getScore("§7>> §l§6Rank: ").setScore(6);
            title.getScore("§7>> §l§6Balance: ").setScore(4);
            title.getScore("§7>> §l§6Island Level:").setScore(2);
            title.getScore("§r     Default").setScore(5);
            title.getScore("§b§a§l§r").setScore(3);
//            Score islandLevel = title.getScore("§r      No island");
//            islandLevel.setScore(1);

            balance = scoreboard.registerNewTeam("");
            balance.addEntry("§b§a§l§r");
            balance.setPrefix("§r    $");
        }




        initializeListeners(pluginManager);

        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, () -> {

            if (BalanceInit.requiresSave) {

                BalanceInit.CHANGED.forEach(((uuid, bal) -> {
                    config.set("player-data.balance." + uuid, bal.toInt());
                }));
                BalanceInit.CHANGED.clear();
                BalanceInit.requiresSave = false;

                saveConfig();
            }
            if (requiresSave) saveConfig();

            if (!playerScoreboardNeedsUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                for (Player p : playerScoreboardNeedsUpdate) {

//                    if (balance == null) {
                        //System.out.println("Balance is null");
//                        continue;
//                    };
                    balance.setSuffix("" + Economy.getBalance(p));
                    p.setScoreboard(scoreboard);
                }
            }
        },40,40);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        super.onDisable();

        FileConfiguration config = getConfig();

        BalanceInit.CHANGED.forEach(((uuid, balance) -> {
            config.set("player-data.balance." + uuid, balance.toInt());
        }));

        saveConfig();
    }

    private void initializeListeners(PluginManager pm) {
        pm.registerEvents(new PlayerJoinEvent(),this);
    }

    public static String getPluginName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

It works fine for the first iteration, it sets my scoreboard to my balance, but then every iteration after it just returns null. I cannot find any reason to this.

JoinListener:

```
package io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.listeners;

import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.Main;
import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.common.chat.Message;
import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.init.BalanceInit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

import java.util.UUID;

public class PlayerJoinEvent implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    private void onPlayerJoin(org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();

        if (!BalanceInit.check(uuid)) {
            Message.broadcastWelcome(player);
            Message.sendWelcome(player, BalanceInit.getAndAdd(uuid));
        }
        else {
            Message.sendWB(player, BalanceInit.getAndAdd(uuid));
        }

        event.setJoinMessage(" ");
    }
}
package io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.listeners;

import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.Main;
import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.common.chat.Message;
import io.github.github9636dev.CustomSkyblock.core.init.BalanceInit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

import java.util.UUID;

public class PlayerJoinEvent implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    private void onPlayerJoin(org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();

        if (!BalanceInit.check(uuid)) {
            Message.broadcastWelcome(player);
            Message.sendWelcome(player, BalanceInit.getAndAdd(uuid));
        }
        else {
            Message.sendWB(player, BalanceInit.getAndAdd(uuid));
        }

        event.setJoinMessage(" ");
    }
}
```

The version is:

```
CraftBukkit version git-Spigot-21fe707-741a1bd (MC: 1.8.8) (Implementing API version 1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
```

Comment: This can't be the code that you runned, because the line 102 doesn't contains balance and you have a null check before using the value. EDIT: I just tested it myself, and it seems to be working (on spigot 1.8.8)

Comment: I changed it to prevent the error from accuring, sorry I was not clear in the thread. Im on 1.8.8 as well?

Comment: Ok, but for me it works. So can you [edit] your post to make a [mre]? Can you show your join listener ? Also yes, you are on 1.8.8 too

Comment: I edited it and added the join listener, I also put the version. I am using jdk 8 for my project. Ty for your time